# Delphi - How to set suiImageButton vertically in suiToolbar?

Tags: delphi

I'm using delphi 7 with tsuiToolbar and tsuiImageButton. In this case i want set toolbar vertically with tsuitoolbar include inside the toolbar there are tsuiImageButtons for menu items. TsuiImageButton also placed vertically.

At a moment, i've finished set tsuiToolbar in vertical with `align=alLeft`.  When i placed first tsuiImageButton at inside tsuiToolbar, its oke. But second tsuiImageButton cannot placed below first tsuiImageButton. The second tsuiImageButton automatically place beside of first tsuiImageButton.

And how can i fix it for placing tsuiImageButton below each other?

Comment: I don't know this `TSuiToolbar` component, but I found the [source for it here](http://code1.okbase.net/codefile/SUIReg.pas_201211247953_41.htm). Since it is based on the standard `TToolBar`, it may behave equally. With the `TSuiToolBar` aligned left, try adding a couple of `TSuiToolButton`s with the `New button` popup menu item. Don't mind the buttons placement while adding. Then grab the right edge of the `TSuiToolBar` and  move it a few pixels right, then back. This rearranges the buttons vertically in the standard `TToolBar`, maybe also in `TSuiToolBar.

Comment: The key is that `TSuiToolBar.Wrapable = True` and that all `TSuitToolButton.Wrap = True`, except the last one.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, thank for your advice. I have tried both. But still not working. If I right click on suiToolbar and add new button with style=tbsSeparator/tbsButton or else, and set it wrap=true, suiImageButton can go down. If I add suiImagebutton or suiButton, its placed beside first one.

Comment: Try also how it behaves at run time.

Comment: Yeah, and with new button and set its property wrap=true, the suiImageButton can be placed below other suiImageButton. Oke, @TomBrunberg, i accepted your answer method.Thanks you very much. But I can't mark it. Maybe you can help me to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `TSuiToolBar.Wrapable = True` and all buttons `Wrap` property as: `TSuitToolButton.Wrap = True`.

It may not be visible at design time (try to force an update by resizing the `TSuiToolBar`), but it will be at run time.